# I am not able to apply the grid tool

Tags: mesh

Grid fill is not working.I am attaching the ss below.Plz check and tell where i have got it wrong. Whenever i try grid fill on this edge loop it says "Select two edge loop".

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thanks but i figured it out i guess.The no of vertices were odd (19) so that was causing grid tool not to word. I added another vertex and then it worked.

Comment: you could just delete your question then, or else add an answer yourself to help others...